# Future of salesforce developer

Tags: future

I'm planning to switch my career to sales force but a question in my mind that made me ask this question..How will be the growth of sales developers in future?? Also job market?

Comment: This question o way related to programming, So will be closed. There are several top technologies around why you ask for Salesforce, answer hides in it.

Comment: salesforce is growing rapidly, and so is the need for skilled professionals. I jumped into it nearly 2 years ago and haven't regretted that for a day.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest - I don't know what I should put in answer to your question...
It is this kind of question "How world will look in 10 years?".

But what I can tell you right now and be sure of it:

- Salesforce is great platform - easy(for beginners), powerful(for advanced), quick and have very good community.

Many people see cloud technology as future. Also based on my experience still more and more firms chose Salesforce as they CRM.